# html link page outside of webserver

Tags: html, webserver, href

I have web server and I need to link some html files (some flash files that are opening like html) that are on one network drive. It is not possible to put the  files on a webserver because there are 700Gb of files to upload.

All possible variants of

```
href="10.10.10.3/path/file.html"
href="http://10.10.10.3/path/file.html"
href="file:///10.10.10.3/path/file.html"
```

have been attempted, but for example if I put the address

```
href="file://///10.10.10.33/path/file.html"
```

I get the page.

But with href it does not open.
I understand that browsers security policy, but is there any way to connect
html pages with  with another html pages on another disk (not web server).
One of solution is maybe to install web server on that other machine and put these html files on webserver and they try to catch them, but for static files i don't need web server.

Comment: Using the `file` pseudo protocol to access some object is working, but it refers to _the client side's file system_. That might make sense in a one person in house usage scenario, but that's all. You can indeed use a second http server. The http server just implements the way _how_ the object (file) is accessed, it is irrelevant if the objects are static files or something dynamic. For example images in the internet typically are static files too, yet they obviously are accessed using a http server. Or you simply export a file system share to the existing http server and serve that.

Comment: you could use something like http://fenixwebserver.com/ on the other machine then connect to the remote files using that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceptable solution for us was to install web server on storage network drive and fetch data from there. Security does not allow to fetch data from paths like: c://.. for example

Answer (score 0):

Could you map the folder to your own web server to point to the  remote location

websserver/remotefolder/ --- > /10.10.10.3/path/

in your html access

websserver/remotefolder/file.html

your web server would then go to the network location to get the file. it depends where your Web Server is located, not sure of your infrastructure

Comment: so is your webserver on the same machine as the files

Comment: no. it is on another machine on intranet. on some kind of file server. i think that the best way to do these is install web server on file server and share files on that way..

Comment: i have more apps on that web server, and mapping remote location as web server root is not good idea. i would rather install another web server on machine where are remote files.